# Babysitting Application

Tags: java

The question is quite lengthy but i hope the information I have provided is sufficient. All the code works except for the point where I have to construct a `BaysittingJob` object and display its values. Thank you so much.

I cannot get the application to output the desired results. It is supposed to:

1. Display a job number with two digits of the year and a four digit sequential number
2. The assined babysitter based on the baby sitter code selected (code is from 1 to 3)
3. The number of children
4. The number of hours worked
5. A fee based on the number of hours worked and the babysitter selected
   If babysitter code is 1, $7 per hour fee is charged
   If babysitter code is 2 or 3, fee is $9 per hour for the first child and $4 per additional hour for each additional child

`BabysittingJob`

```
public class BabysittingJob {

    private int jobNumber;
    private int babysitterCode;
    private String babysitter;
    private int childrenNumber;
    private int hoursWorked;
    private double fee;

    public BabysittingJob(int year, int sequentialNumber, int babysitterCode, int childrenNumber, int hoursWorked, String babysitter) {
        year = year % 2000;
        int jobNumber = ((year * 10000) + sequentialNumber);
        if (babysitterCode == 1) {
            babysitter = "Cindy";
        } else if (babysitterCode == 2) {
            babysitter = "Greg";
        } else if (babysitterCode == 3) {
            babysitter = "Marcia";
        }
    }

    {

        if (babysitterCode == 1) {
            fee = hoursWorked * 7 * childrenNumber;
        } else if (babysitterCode > 1 && childrenNumber == 1) {
            fee = hoursWorked * 9 * childrenNumber;
        } else if (babysitterCode > 1 && childrenNumber > 1) {
            fee = (hoursWorked * 9) + ((--childrenNumber) * hoursWorked * 4);
        }
    }

    public void displayResult() {
        System.out.println("Your job number is:" + jobNumber + "Your baby sitter is:" + babysitter
                + "The number of children is:" + childrenNumber + "The number of hours worked is:"
                + hoursWorked + "Your fee is $:" + fee);
    }
}
```

`CreateBabysittingJob`...

```
import java.util.Scanner;

public class CreateBabysittingJob {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Scanner input = new Scanner(System.in);
        System.out.print("Enter year.");
        int year = input.nextInt();
        while (year < 2013 || year > 2025) {
            System.out.println("Enter a year between 2013 and 2025");
            year = input.nextInt();
        }
        System.out.print("Enter job number");
        int jobNumber = input.nextInt();
        while (jobNumber < 1 || jobNumber > 9999) {
            System.out.println("Enter a number between 1 and 9999");
            jobNumber = input.nextInt();
        }
        System.out.print("Enter babysitter code");
        int babysitterCode = input.nextInt();
        while (babysitterCode < 1 || babysitterCode > 3) {
            System.out.println("Enter a number between 1 and 3");
            babysitterCode = input.nextInt();
        }
        System.out.print("Enter number of children");
        int childrenNumber = input.nextInt();
        while (childrenNumber < 1 || childrenNumber > 9) {
            System.out.println("Enter a number between 1 and 9");
            childrenNumber = input.nextInt();
        }
        System.out.print("Enter number of hours");
        int hoursWorked = input.nextInt();
        while (hoursWorked < 1 || hoursWorked > 12) {
            System.out.println("Enter a number between 1 and 12");
            hoursWorked = input.nextInt();
        }
        BabysittingJob ca = new BabysittingJob(year, jobNumber, babysitterCode, childrenNumber, hoursWorked);
        ca.displayResult();
    }
}
```

Comment: Can you specify the current output and what you would expect as a correct one?

Comment: job number is 0, baby sitter is null, the number of children is 0, the number of hours worked is 0, and the fee is 0.

Comment: my inputs were Year:2013, job number: 5, baby sitter code: 3, number of children: 2, number of hours: 3

Comment: NedZepplin got it. It's exactly that. Just write it down as an answer.

Comment: sorry what do you mean?

Comment: NedZepplin had added a comment saying that you have to assign the parameters of BabysittingJob constructor to its private variables, but apparently it was deleted (dont know why).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to assign the class constructor parameters to its private variables:

```
public class BabysittingJob {

    private int jobNumber;
    private int babysitterCode;
    private String babysitter;
    private int childrenNumber;
    private int hoursWorked;
    private double fee;

    public BabysittingJob(int year, int sequentialNumber, int babysitterCode, int childrenNumber, int hoursWorked, String babysitter) {
        year = year % 2000;
        this.childrenNumber = childrenNumber;
        this.hoursWorked = hoursWorked;
        this.babysitterCode = babysitterCode;
        this.jobNumber = ((year * 10000) + sequentialNumber);

        if (babysitterCode == 1) {
            this.babysitter = "Cindy";
        } else if (babysitterCode == 2) {
            this.babysitter = "Greg";
        } else if (babysitterCode == 3) {
            this.babysitter = "Marcia";
        }

        if (babysitterCode == 1) {
            this.fee = hoursWorked * 7 * childrenNumber;
        } else if (babysitterCode > 1 && childrenNumber == 1) {
            this.fee = hoursWorked * 9 * childrenNumber;
        } else if (babysitterCode > 1 && childrenNumber > 1) {
            this.fee = (hoursWorked * 9) + ((--childrenNumber) * hoursWorked * 4);
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

There are a number of peculiarities that I've found...

First of all, you define the constructor of `BabysittingJob` as...

```
public BabysittingJob(int year, int sequentialNumber, int babysitterCode, int childrenNumber, int hoursWorked, String babysitter) {
```

But you try and construct an instance of it using

```
BabysittingJob ca = new BabysittingJob(year, jobNumber, babysitterCode, childrenNumber, hoursWorked);
```

This is missing the `babysitter`.  The problem is, you are actually determining the `babysitter` value based on the `babysitterCode` within the constructor...

```
public BabysittingJob(int year, int sequentialNumber, int babysitterCode, int childrenNumber, int hoursWorked, String babysitter) {
    year = year % 2000;
    int jobNumber = ((year * 10000) + sequentialNumber);
    if (babysitterCode == 1) {
        babysitter = "Cindy";
    } else if (babysitterCode == 2) {
        babysitter = "Greg";
    } else if (babysitterCode == 3) {
        babysitter = "Marcia";
    }
}
```

The problem is, the `babysitter` is shadowing the class instance field of the same name, meaning that anything your assign to this variable will have no meaning out side of the constructor, leaving the instance field as `null`

The other peculiarity is you have the following piece of code just hanging out there in the middle of no where...

```
{
    if (babysitterCode == 1) {
        fee = hoursWorked * 7 * childrenNumber;
    } else if (babysitterCode > 1 && childrenNumber == 1) {
        fee = hoursWorked * 9 * childrenNumber;
    } else if (babysitterCode > 1 && childrenNumber > 1) {
        fee = (hoursWorked * 9) + ((--childrenNumber) * hoursWorked * 4);
    }
}
```

I "think" you want to within the constructor, for example...

```
public BabysittingJob(int year, int sequentialNumber, int babysitterCode, int childrenNumber, int hoursWorked) {
    year = year % 2000;
    int jobNumber = ((year * 10000) + sequentialNumber);
    if (babysitterCode == 1) {
        babysitter = "Cindy";
    } else if (babysitterCode == 2) {
        babysitter = "Greg";
    } else if (babysitterCode == 3) {
        babysitter = "Marcia";
    }
    if (babysitterCode == 1) {
        fee = hoursWorked * 7 * childrenNumber;
    } else if (babysitterCode > 1 && childrenNumber == 1) {
        fee = hoursWorked * 9 * childrenNumber;
    } else if (babysitterCode > 1 && childrenNumber > 1) {
        fee = (hoursWorked * 9) + ((--childrenNumber) * hoursWorked * 4);
    }
}
```

Which I think should get you closer to what you want

Other things you are going to need to fix...

- You never assign the parameter `childrenNumber` to the class instance field `childrenNumber` in the constructor...`this.childrenNumber = childrenNumber`
- You never assign the parameter `hoursWorked` to the class instance field `hoursWorked` in the constructor...`this.hoursWorked = hoursWorked`